# Mac Terminal Commands - how to come back after forgetting to close quotation marks

Tags: git, heroku, terminal

Warning: Noob question ahead!

I'm using Heroku, and have forgetting to close the quotation marks when committing:

```
localhost: app myMac$ git commit -m "testing
>
```

As you can see the last `"` is missing on the end of testing. Now I've got the `>` sign and I'm unsure how to get out of it? This must be a trivial thing but I just can't get a grip of it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a `bash` question than a `git` one.

For a forgotten quotation mark, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/655558/190730) on superuser.com.

Basically, press `ctrl-c` to cancel the current command, then the up arrow `↑` to retrieve your last line typed.

```
localhost: app myMac$ git commit -m "testing
>
```

Whoops, hit `ctrl-c`.

```
localhost: app myMac$
```

Now press the up arrow `↑`...

```
localhost: app myMac$ git commit -m "testing
```

and try again.

Comment: ...or `Ctrl-p` instead of the `↑`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `"` and press enter. If you want to fix the commit message to remove the new line run:

```
git commit --amend -m "Replacement commit"
```

This will change the last commit message to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell knows there is a missing `"`.  You can continue typing your message and finally enter the last `"` and it should take.

And if this fails there is always `git commit --amend` option to correct what went wrong.